# In Windows, how can I give other applications the ability to programmatically launch my application?

Tags: windows, integration

I've written a Windows application. I want other applications to be able to programmatically launch my application. How can I achieve that and what are the considerations involved?

Edit: To clarify, I'm not asking how other applications can launch my application; I'm asking what I can do to ensure that other applications are able to launch my application.

Comment: The simple answer is that they only need to use the system() function with a path to your application. But you are probably looking for something else therefore you need to be more precise: do you want your application to interoperate with the others (and in which ways), do you want them to launch yours at specific time of days, ...?

Comment: Yes, that is simple, but it seems that you've just kicked the can. How would another application know the path to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to launch an application without having to know the explicit path to where it is installed, you need to register it with Windows by adding it to the App Paths registry tree.

This is typically done during application installation.

See [MSDN - Application Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Bruce, do I understand correctly that the App Paths registry tree is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software, and is therefore subject to [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- the implication being that my application's registration would be unreadable by applications that have a different 32 vs. 64-bit architecture than my application?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: I did an experiment and found that both 32 and 64 bit applications can read App Paths registry values written by 32 and 64 bit applications. This doesn't square with my understanding of registry redirection, but it does establish that Bruce's solution is complete, and I don't need to fear that my application will be undiscoverable by some portion of applications because of an architecture mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, there is no security preventing an application from running another application (in user mode at least, to run in admin mode would require the other program to be executed in admin mode, or else to prompt the user to run it in admin mode). The other application simply needs to know the path to the location of your .exe file and it can execute it. If the other program doesn't know the exact path, but it knows where to look and what your program .exe is called, it can search for it in the file system before executing it as well.

As for specifically how they would launch your program's .exe file, this will depend on the the language their program is written in as to how the system API to launch the .exe is called.

Comment: My questiom here is what does firefox has different and can be opened with "start firefox"?

Comment: @Leon Those applications are registered under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` registry key.

Comment: Jeff, to paraphrase your answer, you're saying I could take no additional measures on my end, and my application will be launchable by any application that knows the path to my executable or is willing & able to find that path by searching the file system. Okay, but that seems restrictive. I'd like my application to be launchable by applications that don't know the path to my executable and aren't willing or able to find that path by searching the file system.

Comment: What information do the other applications know about your application? If all they know is the name, then Bruce's solution to register the executable path in the system registry is a good solution.